# Bootstrap heading collapses for a second before popping back?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Very new to HTML, CSS, and Bootstrap. Having trouble getting collapse to work right.

I've included a gif of my issue. I'm using bootstrap, and when trying to use collapse on an H4 tag it isn't working right. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

[GIF](https://i.gyazo.com/5184c7d9101b43ff5b04dd70193f3462.mp4)

Here is my code.

```css
.jumbotron {
  background-color: #2E2D88;
  color: white;
}


/* Adds borders for tabs */

.tab-content {
  border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 10px;
}

.nav-tabs {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<html lang='en'>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <title>Bootstrap Tutorial</title>
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <h4>Column 1</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <h4>Column 2</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <h4>Column 3</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <h4>Column 4</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <h4><a href="#col1content" data-toggle="collapse">Column 1</a></h4>
        <div id="col1content" class="collapse">Text lorem ipsum.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are importing Bootstrap JS library which version is **v3** while CSS version is **v4**. Both CSS and JS have to be the same version.

Import v4 JS library instead then it would work.

```css
.jumbotron {
  background-color: #2E2D88;
  color: white;
}


/* Adds borders for tabs */

.tab-content {
  border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 10px;
}

.nav-tabs {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<html lang='en'>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <title>Bootstrap Tutorial</title>
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <h4>Column 1</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <h4>Column 2</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <h4>Column 3</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <h4>Column 4</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <h4><a href="#col1content" data-toggle="collapse">Column 1</a></h4>
        <div id="col1content" class="collapse">Text lorem ipsum.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!